# Android Studio Nesting ScrollView in a Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android studio and have been messing around with this layout for the last hour or two. I want the whole screen to be able to scroll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:padding="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/emailEditText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcomeTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/welcome_text"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="23dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/introTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/intro_text"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/welcomeTextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/learnMoreButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pink_button"
            android:text="@string/learn_more_button"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/signUpButton"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/introTextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/navy_button"
            android:text="@string/sign_up_button"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/learnMoreButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/learnMoreButton" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="89dp"
            android:layout_height="74dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person_outline_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailEditText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signInButton"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pink_button"
        android:text="@string/sign_in_button"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordEditText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/or"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fbSignInButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signInButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fbSignInButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pink_button"
        android:text="@string/fb_button"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/orTextView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried putting the scrollview nested inside the main constraint layout and I have also changed the layout to a Scrollview layout and nested a Constraint layout which I also could not get to work. Can someone explain where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As scrollview is only capable of handling a single view, I would suggest you to wrap everything within a Linear Layout 
Use the following code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

//PUT ALL OF YOUR ELEMENTS IN HERE
//STARTING WITH...
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:padding="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/emailEditText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

..............REMAINING ELEMENTS.............

//AND ENDING WITH
<Button
    android:id="@+id/fbSignInButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/pink_button"
    android:text="@string/fb_button"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/orTextView" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```